# Get authenticated user entity Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I use Spring MVC + Spring Security in my project. And I need get user entity after user authenticates and across his session. For example, in order to print his name on my **welcome page** like: `Welcome, ${user.firstName}!` or get his list of companies on **another page**:

```
<c:forEach items="${user.userCompanies}" var="company">
    ${company.name}
</c:forEach>
```

etc.
Could you help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [taglib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/taglibs.html) provided by Spring Security.
To get the username, use:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

Comment: Thank you. But as far as I know principal.username gives me only UserDetails class fields like username, password. What about custom fields of my entity (like userCompanies etc.)?

Comment: I think you can access any property of your custom `UserDetails` object, because the [tag's implementation](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/taglibs/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/taglibs/authz/AuthenticationTag.java#L100-L101) uses reflection to get it. I guess `principal.companies` should work.

Comment: I used `<sec:authentication property="principal.firstName"/>` on my jsp and got  `Invalid property 'principal.firstName' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken]:` exception :(

Comment: If you look at the stacktrace of that exception, you can see that it's thrown inside `BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue()`. Quote from the javadoc of that method: `Throws:
InvalidPropertyException - if there is no such property or if the property isn't readable`. Which means that you actually don't have a `firstName` property in the object returned by `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`.

Comment: But you said that I can access **any property of your custom UserDetails object, because the tag's implementation uses reflection to get it.**

Comment: Of course you can, **in case** you made it sure that your custom `UserDetails` object actually gets into the security context. Do you have a properly configured `UserDetailsService`? However this doesn't have anything to do with your original question, so you will need to open another one if you have difficulty with that.

Comment: Ok. I will form my question and open new topic. Thank you!