# UserDetailsService config for properly getting user

Tags: spring, spring-security

I create this topic from my previous one [Get authenticated user entity Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225484/get-authenticated-user-entity-spring-mvc/15225612#15225612) where I asked question about properly getting authenticated user entity. I adviced that Principal object (for example, on my view `<sec:authentication property="principal.customFieldName" />`) can has access to my custom fields if my UserDetailsService configuration is right. Does my UserDetailsService configured properly to accomplish this functionality?

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hibernateUserDao")
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        UserDetails user = userDAO.findByLogin(userName);

        if (user == null) {
            logger.error("User was not found! Input login: " + userName);
        }

        return buildUserFormUserEntity(user);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User buildUserFormUserEntity(UserDetails userDetails) {
        boolean enableStatus = userDetails.isEnabled();
        String userName = userDetails.getLogin();
        String password = userDetails.getPassword();
        boolean enabled = enableStatus;
        boolean accountNonExpired = enableStatus;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = enableStatus;
        boolean accountNonLocked = enableStatus;

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userDetails.getRole()));

        User springSecurityUser = new User(userName, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        return springSecurityUser;
    }

    public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some additional steps to be able succesfully use

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.customFieldName" />
```

on some page:

1. Add your custom user object that implements `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` interface. The simpliest way to do it is to extend existing `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` class: `class CutomUser extends User`
2. Add your `customFieldName` property to `CutomUser` class.
3. Use `CutomUser` as a return type in your `UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(...)` method. Do not forget to fill `customFieldName` at this moment.

Comment: But I already have this methods. Will not interfere with the new methods of the old?

Comment: Sorry, It looks like I missed it out. Your UserDetailsService class is configured propely. Just one question: where do you set the value of your `customFieldName` property?

Comment: Somewhere in `loadUserByUsername` method

Comment: But this value dynamically. Or simply I didn't understand enough. Could you show me a small example?

Comment: You mean that the content of `user.userCompanies` may be changed when user is logged in?

Comment: Some content may be changed, some not, I want full access to authenticated user object

Comment: Link some dynamic data to the principal is not good idea from perfomance point of view. A principal is stored in HTTP session (session scoped variable). So all linked objects wan't be garbage collected (even if they are useless for future requests). Request scope is much more appropriate for dynamic data. In your Spring MVC controller get principal (you can add it as method parameter an it will be automatically populated). Make DB request (use principal's name as a parameter, load companies).

Comment: I suppose that you have a user in DB that has a collection of companies. Put a collection of companies into Spring MVC model (making it available to your jsp view). Then iterate trough this collection in your JSP and print values. So actually you will have two representations for the same user: principal (session scoped, for authentication) and DB user (matched with principal by username). Hope this helps. Feel free to post any questions if I was not clear.